# Tagged PDF: Access /Pages object from pdftex?

Tags: pdftex, tagged-pdf

I'm working on tagging a PDF produced in pdflatex, and I've reached the point that I believe I will need to add a reference to the `/Pages` object in the catalog.  (Specifically, in the `/ParentTree` under `/StructTreeRoot`, though the standard document is pretty cryptic, to me, about what really belongs here.).  But the pdftex manual doesn't seem to reveal any mechanism for doing this.  Is there one?

Alternatively, if there's a better way to tag PDF with pdflatex ("switch to ConTeXt" doesn't qualify), I'd be glad to avoid reinventing the wheel.

Comment: Try    \pdfpageref\c@page  .

Comment: I don't think that's what I'm looking for.  I want the /Pages object in the pdf file, not the current page.

Answer (score 1):

The /ParentTree has nothing directly to do with the /Pages dictionary.
It is an array of references, one for each "virtual page"; these include all annotations, images and image masks, XObjects as well as the actual pages.

The reference for an actual page is to an array of the structural parent of each piece of Marked Content, as indexed by its MCID integer.
None of this is of any use unless you are generating a fully tagged PDF.
I'm currently writing a LaTeX package for exactly this, using pdfTeX as engine.

Contact me off-list if you want more specific help, or an example.

Comment: I'd love to contact you off-list; how can I do so?

Comment: You can find links to some of my work here: